# EF Core 1-to-many without configuring "the many" side

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'd want to have relation One File with Many User, but I don't want to have `List<File>` in User class

I found that I can just use `HasOne()` during configuration, but how can I specify which property is an actual ForeignKey?

```
public class File
{
    ...
    public Guid UploadedById { get; set; }

    public User UploadedBy { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    I don't want to have 

    public List<File> Files { get; set; } = new List<File>();

    here
}

public class FileConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<File>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<File> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.HasOne(x => x.UploadedBy)... how to specify key?
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you not want to use attributes?

Comment: @JasperKent I tend to believe that Fluent way is cleaner :P

Comment: `.WithMany()…` - see [Relationships - Manual configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration)